# Might be a small bug in moving the arm tutorial, how to correct such issues?

Tags: ros, python, module, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using electric on Ubuntu 11.10

While going through the tutorial at : http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20arm%20through%20a%20Cartesian%20pose%20trajectory

I was unable to run it using the python client, But directly using the command line as explained worked nicely. I got

```
$python scripts/test_ik_trajectory_tutorial.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/test_ik_trajectory_tutorial.py", line 69, in 
    success = call_execute_cartesian_ik_trajectory("/base_link", positions, orientations)
  File "scripts/test_ik_trajectory_tutorial.py", line 19, in call_execute_cartesian_ik_trajectory
    header = roslib.msg.Header()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'msg'
```

This seemed like a straight forward issue and must be faced by other people as well, but I couldn't find the answer to exact error. Luckily when I googled with 'roslib.msg.Header()' and in google search page saw

#4784 (actionlib uses roslib.msg.Header instead of rospy.Header .............

I simply changed the

```
header = roslib.msg.Header()
```

to

```
header = rospy.Header();
```

and it worked!!!!

My question is : Is it specific to electric? Or only I am facing this? Or is it a valid bug? On my machine at /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/ there is no msg.py file but msgs.py and when I changed msg to msgs I got error on Header().

However if this is a valid bug (though small one then) how could it be corrected on the tutorial?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40549/might-be-a-small-bug-in-moving-the-arm-tutorial,-how-to-correct-such-issues?/) by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2012-08-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [agoto](https://answers.ros.org/users/3109/agoto/) on 2012-09-18**:
The same correction worked on Fuerte with Ubuntu 12.04. I think it is pretty safe to edit the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That tutorial looks out of date. Until someone notices, problems like that tend to be overlooked.

Since ros.org is a wiki, you can edit it yourself.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0